# Getting 5 digit Zip Code from string Data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

I have a string that contains City,State Zip, and Country. I have been able to get the City and State from the string into a separate column but I ran into issues getting the zip code pulled out. Here is an example of the data I am pulling from.

Columbus,OH 43219, United States

The code I have tried is this

```
Replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP], CHARINDEX(',', C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP])))),',','')as City,

   left(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP], CHARINDEX(',', C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP])+1, LEN(C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP])-(CHARINDEX('', C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP])-1)))),2)as State,

   dbo.udf_GetNumeric(Right(LTRIM(RTRIM(Substring(C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP], CHARINDEX(',', C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP])+1, LEN(C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP])-(CHARINDEX('',C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP]-1)))),2))as Zip,
```

I included the code I used to pull the City and State because I mirrored the line for the Zip code off of the State line but I keep getting the error below. I can't figure out where I am missing the argument for the ltrim. Any advice would be welcome.

Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
The ltrim function requires 1 argument(s).
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 52
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: try `dbo.udf_GetNumeric(Right(LTRIM(RTRIM(Substring(C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP], CHARINDEX(',', C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP])+1, LEN(C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP])-(CHARINDEX('', C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP])-1)))),2))as Zip,`

Comment: Watch out for that udf_getnumeric function as some states have a leading 0 in their zip codes.

Comment: This is just a syntax error. You are missing a closing parenthesis at the end. But hopefully you are able to fix the design and not store all these pieces of data in the same tuple. It is painful as you are discovering, it also violates 1NF.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! I will remember this.

Comment: Could there be a [ZIP+4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_Code#ZIP+4) code in the string?

Comment: Thank you Sean. You were correct. One missing parenthesis was all it was...What do you mean by "hopefully you are able to fix the design and not store all these pieces of data in the same tuple."?    Also what do you mean 1NF?

Comment: @NewCoder04 1NF= First Normal Form, something you should do with all your data stored in a database. It's usually considered bad design having a string like this, and then you need to "convert" it to something you can use...

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras Thank you for the explanation. Unfortunately this is a database that I am migrating from...that is why I have to separate the string into different columns in a more structured database. Its been a nightmare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
select case when patindex('% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9],%', c) > 0 then
SUBSTRING(c, patindex('% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9],%', c) + 1, 5)
else '' end as zipCode
from
(
select 'Columbus,OH 43219, United States' as c
union all
select 'Chicago,IL 60626, United States' as c
) c
```

Comment: Quick question. If I had over 5000 records I'm moving, would I need to do a separate Union all statement for each distinct Address string? If yes, is there a way that I could specify a type of string in the from (select)?

Comment: This is just an example. Just use this part `case when patindex('% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9],%', c) > 0 then
SUBSTRING(c, patindex('% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9],%', c) + 1, 5)
else '' end as zipCode` as part of your own `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with substrings:

```
DECLARE @address NVARCHAR(500) = 'Columbus,OH 43219, United States'

SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@address, CHARINDEX(',',@address) + 1, LEN(@address)),0,CHARINDEX(',',SUBSTRING(@address, CHARINDEX(',',@address) + 1, LEN(@address)))),
    CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@address, CHARINDEX(',',@address) + 1, LEN(@address)),0,CHARINDEX(',',SUBSTRING(@address, CHARINDEX(',',@address) + 1, LEN(@address))))) + 1,LEN(@address))
```

Answer (score 0):

For "City", buried in there you have

```
- (CHARINDEX('', C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP])-1)
```

For "Zip", in the same spot you have

```
 - (CHARINDEX('', C.[BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP]-1))
```

Note that the closing parenthesese are different. Looks like you need to move one of those two to "before" that -1.

Comment: ...that's what appears to be wrong with your code sample. There may be better ways to write this; SQL is horrible when it comes to parsing and processing it strings, because that's not what its meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with complex string expressions `APPLY` is your best friend. You can use it to make your code much DRYer (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself). This makes code much cleaner and easier to debug.

```
DECLARE @BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP VARCHAR(200) = ' Columbus ,OH 43219, United States ';

SELECT
  City    = SUBSTRING(f.String, a.Head,  a.Pos-1),
  [State] = SUBSTRING(f.String, a.Pos+1, b.Pos-a.Pos-1), 
  Zip     = SUBSTRING(f.String, b.Pos+1, c.Pos-b.Pos-1),
  Country = SUBSTRING(f.String, c.Pos+1, 200) -- BONUS
FROM        (VALUES(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE( -- All trimming (outer & inner) in 1 spot
             @BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP,', ',','),' ,',','))))) AS f(String)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',f.String),1))            AS a(Pos,Head)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',f.String,a.Pos+1)))      AS b(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',f.String,b.Pos+1)))      AS c(Pos);
```

**Returns:**

```
City        State    Zip     Country
----------- -------- ------- -----------------
Columbus    OH       43219   United States
```

Against a table it looks like this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (SomeId INT IDENTITY, BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP VARCHAR(200));
INSERT  @table VALUES ('Columbus,OH 43219, United States'),('Chicago ,IL 60625, United States')

SELECT t.SomeId, f.City, f.[State], f.[Zip], f.Country 
FROM   @table AS t
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    City    = SUBSTRING(f.String, a.Head,  a.Pos-1),
    [State] = SUBSTRING(f.String, a.Pos+1, b.Pos-a.Pos-1), 
    Zip     = SUBSTRING(f.String, b.Pos+1, c.Pos-b.Pos-1),
    Country = SUBSTRING(f.String, c.Pos+1, 200)
  FROM        (VALUES(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(
               t.BILLING_CITYSTATEZIP,', ',','),' ,',','))))) AS f(String)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',f.String),1))            AS a(Pos,Head)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',f.String,a.Pos+1)))      AS b(Pos)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',f.String,b.Pos+1)))      AS c(Pos)
) AS f;
```

**Returns:**

```
SomeId   City       State  Zip    Country
-------- ---------- ------ ------ ----------------
1        Columbus   OH     43219  United States
2        Chicago    IL     60625  United States
```